# Does weak convergence of non-atomic measures to a non-atomic limit preserve absolute continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu_n$, $\mu$ and $\nu$ be non-atomic Borel measures on a common Hausdorff topological space, such that the $\mu_n$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$. Does weak convergence $\mu_n \to \mu$ (in the sense of probability theory, i.e. defined in terms of bounded continuous functions) imply that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$?

Without excluding atoms the answer is no, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199078/does-weak-convergence-of-measures-preserve-absolute-continuity).

If the answer is still no in the non-atomic situation above, would it make a difference to assume that all measures be regular Borel or Radon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $\mu$ be the uniform distribution on the circle and let $\nu$ be the Lesbegue measure. Let $\mu_n$ be the uniform distribution on the annulus $B[0,1]\setminus B[0,1-1/n]$. Then $\mu_n$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, but $\mu_n\to \mu$ weakly. As $\mu$ is supported on  a null-set, $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to the Lesbegue measure.

Note that all these measures are Radon.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want a 1d example, let $\nu$ be the Lesbegue measure, $\mu$ the Cantor distribution. Then, for $C_1=[0,1/3]\cup [2/3,1]$ and $C_{n+1}=1/3 C_n\cup (2/3+1/3 C_n)$, define $\mu_n$ to be the uniform distribution on $C_n$. Then, $\mu_n\to \mu$ weakly and you get the same result.

Comment: Thank you for these very clear examples!